I have a long string that I want to remove most of excpet for specific details
MySchedule UK & Ireland*************** (Custo_MHS00801682LIPHOOK SERVICESESSMy ScheduleEnglish (**************** ScheduleOf 22. Jul 20243My Work2583042ScheduleTrade BoardTimecardRequestsAvallable ShiftsHome Store Events**************; ************* TimeBreakLocationNotes AlertsMon, 22.JulDay OffRecentlyTue, 23 Jul15.00-21.008R -17.45 _18.3000801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DayOpenedWed, 24 Jul12.00 -21.008Rt6:15-17.0000801682 _LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AIl DaySummer HolidaysThu, 25 Jul17.00-22.00SR -19.15 _19.4500801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DaySummer HolidaysFri, 26 Jul17.00- 23.00SR -19.45 _20.3000801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DaySummer HolidaysSat; 27 Jul12.00 -21.008Rt6:15-17.0000801682 _LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AIl DaySummer HolidaysSun, 28.JulNct ScheduledWeek

The stars are just censoring some personal information but this is my schedule for work. I only want to store the days and times which if you look through it you can find eg. 27 Jul12.00 -21.00.
I just cannot come up with a solution for the life of me.
I have been using ocr to capture the info as the website seems to be designed to stop you from using a bot to get all the information. I have attempted using all kinds of different string clean up functions but just cant get them to work.

If I were you, I'd try to use any other avenue than OCR once more - for instance, automating a real browser using Playwright.

You can use Playwright to simulate human actions to navigate a website and directly extract days and times. The code is like:
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('YOUR_LOGIN_URL')  
    page.fill('#username', 'your_username')  
    page.fill('#password', 'your_password')  
    page.click('#login_button') 
    page.wait_for_navigation()
    page.goto('YOUR_SCHEDULE_URL')  

    # find the date class and time class through the inspector
    dates = page.query_selector_all('.date-class') 
    times = page.query_selector_all('.time-class') 

    browser.close()

Or you can use re after extracting a long string. But that requires complex patterns to match.

admitting the format is always in the form DD MMMHH.00( -)HH.00 with variable content in parens
import re
data="""MySchedule UK & Ireland*************** (Custo_MHS00801682LIPHOOK SERVICESESSMy ScheduleEnglish (**************** ScheduleOf 22. Jul 20243My Work2583042ScheduleTrade BoardTimecardRequestsAvallable ShiftsHome Store Events**************; ************* TimeBreakLocationNotes AlertsMon, 22.JulDay OffRecentlyTue, 23 Jul15.00-21.008R -17.45 _18.3000801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DayOpenedWed, 24 Jul12.00 -21.008Rt6:15-17.0000801682 _LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AIl DaySummer HolidaysThu, 25 Jul17.00-22.00SR -19.15 _19.4500801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DaySummer HolidaysFri, 26 Jul17.00- 23.00SR -19.45 _20.3000801682LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AI DaySummer HolidaysSat; 27 Jul12.00 -21.008Rt6:15-17.0000801682 _LIPHOOK SERWCES NORTHStore Open AIl DaySummer HolidaysSun, 28.JulNct ScheduledWeek"""


pattern = '(\d{2}) (\w{3})(\d{2}.00)[ \-]*?(\d{2}.00)'
for res in re.findall(pattern, data):
    print(res)

outputs
('23', 'Jul', '15.00', '21.00')
('24', 'Jul', '12.00', '21.00')
('25', 'Jul', '17.00', '22.00')
('26', 'Jul', '17.00', '23.00')
('27', 'Jul', '12.00', '21.00')

